# Current Sharing Circuit

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, control, buck-boost

I want to use this [TI document](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva826/snva826.pdf?ts=1629380197772&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) to do the current sharing, about this document I have some questions I cannot get it. Could someone give some advice?

1. I do not understand how this circuit works and why it can use an OP Amp to do the current sharing, I read the document several times, but I am still very confused. Can someone explain this in detail?
2. I do not understand how to get this formula, I know the equation 1 to 3, but I do not find any information about equation 4.
   [image]
3. What's the function of C<sub>P</sub>? Can I use a resistor to replace it?

[image]

Comment: Start by what happens when the Master is delivering much more current than the Slave. What does that mean for the voltages across the Rs resistors and thus the voltages Vo1 and Vo2. Will Vo1 > Vo2 or Vo1 < Vo2? This will result in the opamp making its output low or high. That then pushes or pulls current through Rc. That then influences the Slave such that it will deliver more current.

Comment: what are the inputs of the OP Amp? ... what is the result of a change at the OP Amp output?

Comment: Why would you want to replace Cp with a resistor? The circuit shows there needs to be a capacitor. No value is given for Cp, my guess is that it is a small value capacitor. For high frequencies this connects the output of the opamp to the input and that limits the gain making the circuit more stable and prevents oscillations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. I do not understand how this circuit works and why it can use an OP Amp to do the current sharing, I read the document several times,
>    but I am still very confused. Can someone explain this in detail?
> 2. I do not understand how to get this formula, I know the equation 1 to 3, but I do not find any information about equation 4.

It is not nice of Ti's engineer to jump into eq. 4. At the same time, I like his reasoning why he did. Wonder if it was Bob Pease's associates.
I will answer above two questions at once, by a circuitry. I assume you understand the fundamentals of OPA and feedback circuitry.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPiiuE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> 3.1. What's the function of Cp.

It is a loop compensation.

> 3.2. Can I use a resistor to replace it?

I understand why you ask it (?).  Yes you can use a resistor. There are multiple ways to compensate the feedback loop response.

Comment: Hi Jay, 
Your explanation is very well. Thanks.

Comment: Hi jay, can I use email to discuss some other problems with this circuit?

Comment: Hi Jay, 
If I want to draw the bode plot of the buck-boost, do I need to include the current sharing circuit?

Comment: @EEC I think, you need to include all and whatever involved, from input to output, in the analysis in order to get accurate result. Though, It is an honor for me to be considered as an adviser, I believe, you would receive more optimum answers through StackExchange. The key to get a better answer is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270733/where-can-i-find-detailed-rules-and-guidelines).

Comment: Thanks, one more question, Do you know how to choose the OPA in this circuit?
I do not understand why they choose LM8261

Comment: @EEC [LM8261](https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=10&gotoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Flm8261) features "Single RRIO High Output Current & Unlimited Cap Load Op Amp", along with wide range of rail voltage and high-speed, nice packaging, good price, all that is desirable for the switching supply operations. It was initially introduce by National Semiconductors.

Comment: but this OP amp is expensive, could I change to a cheaper one?
but I have no idea how to choose the right OP Amp. can you give me some advice?

Comment: @EEC Of course, [This](https://www.digikey.com/en/blog/a-guide-to-op-amp-selection) and [this](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/operational-amplifier-op-amp/how-to-choose-an-op-amp-buying-guide.php) are on the web, and I like it.

Answer (score 2):

The Op Amp detects the Slave output voltage as a positive error current into Rc to FB for negative feedback .  By raising FB2 , Vo2 must go lower.

FB will equal the internal Vref = 800 mV . Thus the 1st part of eq. 4 is just the normal ratiometric scaling of Vref with \$V_o= (R_{fb2}+R_{fb1})/R_{fb1} *V_{ref}\$.

The 2nd part is the negative feedback gain \$R_{fb2}/R_C\$ for voltage error correction from the open loop gain of the OA now in a negative feedback loop. But the error is relative to the FB voltage.  This is like a simple OA with Vin+=0.8V the internal reference and Vin- being the negative FB input with |Rf/Rin| as the outer loop voltage gain for balancing the two regulators. This gain range only needs to exceed the sum of voltage errors for both regulators by some amount, which I have not computed.

Cp is essential for stability like an internal integrator to all Op Amps. This integrator is external.  The 2 regulators have a limited bandwidth and the error signal Gain Bandwidth must be reduced by Cp to prevent oscillations.  This means the balancing will be lower BW than the BW of each regulator with a damped 1st order response and some phase margin.

This results in a PI control loop with a proportional gain error factor Kp=Rfb2/Rc and an Integral loop gain time constant  Ki=CpRf1

Since each regulator is buck/boost with internal current sensing and extra features for soft-start and zero-valley mode, it should be very stable with no load as long as the layout follows the highly recommended advice.

Other designs that use  Current Sharing by sensing load current with *no load* is a recipe for oscillation,  both trying to stabilize power when there is no demand.  (Having seen this with redundant PSU’s in production, we had to tune to 1% and add 10% preload.

Comment: Hi Tony, 
Thanks for your answer, it is very clear to me.
If I want to draw the bode plot of the buck-boost, do I need to include the current sharing circuit?

Comment: Yes that but is a secondary loop

Comment: Do you know how to choose the OPA in this circuit? I do not understand why they choose LM8261

Comment: Hi I use PSIM to simulate but the result is not correct, could you help me to check>

Comment: Where do you need help?

Comment: Thanks, I solve the problem.

Comment: The OA must be able to work with inputs at Vdd so this OA fits that description (RRIO)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there is a voltage offset between the outputs of the master and slave LDO. The LM8261 subtracts Vo1 and Vo2 then outputs the difference on Vcfb.

Rc is there to change the voltage from Vcfb to a current (you can think of it like a current source) Vcfb/Rc = I. The current I is added to the resistor feedback bridge to 'adjust' the error of the slaves vout to match the masters.

(you can't just drive the FB pin with the voltage Vcfb directly or Fb would equal Vcfb and you would get no voltage feedback to the slave and the control loop would become unstable).

> I do not understand how to get this formula, I know the equation 1 to 3, but I do not find any information about equation 4.

You can solve this just by solving the equation for a resistive divider with the added Rc (the circuit below). Vfb is high impedance so no current flows into it, so only the resistors need to be considered in the current equation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsizzJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> What's the function of Cp. Can I use a resistor to replace it?

No, the capacitor is there to short the AC component of Vo1 to Vcfb, if changed to a resistor it would send a DC gain through to Vcfb and make the loop unequal.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Voltage Spike
If I want to draw the bode plot of the buck-boost, do I need to include the current sharing circuit?

Comment: Who said Vfb was driven directly? It’s a virtual null in linear mode with negative feedback. Current offset is the same function as voltage feedback when the input current is near null.  2. Caps don’t cause a short on AC in Bode  plots

Comment: Please read again it says "you can't drive it directly"